# ServletRequestAware,ServletResponseAware unable recognize by struts version 2.3.24.2

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, httprequest, httpresponse

I have upgraded my Struts project from 2.2.1 to 2.3.24.1.

Available interfaces ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware are showing error since they are deprecated.

```
public HttpServletRequest request;
public HttpServletResponse response;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse() {
    return response;
}
```

Like `setServletRequest/Response()` methods they are setting the HttpServletResquest and Response.

Could anyone suggest how to replace this old code ?

Comment: Why do you say they are deprecated?

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+SHIFT+O :|